# Electrostatics, field and potential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, conservative-field

Are non-uniform fields possible though since electrostatic force is conservative and if we move a test charge through a closed loop in a non-uniform field, work done is not zero?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking for a formal proof, you might like to do a thought experiment moving a test charge *q* in the vicinity of a fixed point charge, *Q* (which, of course, gives an inverse square law field). It's easy to see that the work done by *Q* on *q* if *q* moves 'outwards' away from *Q* is balanced by the work needed to push *q* the same radial amount inwards towards *Q*, and that this applies even if *q* is moving at an angle to the radial direction. In this latter case you need to consider small bits of the path at a time. Any 'tangential' part of the path, or component of the path, involves no work at all. Have I explained this well enough for you to see that the work done in any closed loop, even in this inverse square law field, is zero?

Comment: Wonderful explanation. This argument should always be used when explaining conservative vector fields.

Answer (score 0):

Work around a closed loop in a conservative field is always zero. A field doesn't have to be uniform to be conservative.

It's a difficult concept to get your head around, but there is a beautiful mathematical proof that this is always the case, parting from the definition of a conservative vector field.